# RQ Python "Working outside of application context"

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, redis, python-rq

I'm trying to use Redis & RQ to set the task of sending an email, however, the "RQ Worker" is returning runtime error while using the function to send emails outside q.enqueue works fine.

- **app/routes.py**

  ```
  routes = Blueprint("routes", __name__)
  r = Redis()
  q = Queue(connection=r)

  def sendEmail_task(recipient, message):
      msg = Message("Test Email", sender=("Me", "shawkyelshazly2@gmail.com"), 
      recipients=[recipient])
      msg.body = message
      msg.send(mail)

  @routes.route("/send_email", methods=["POST", "GET"])
  def send_mail():
      if request.method == "POST":
          recipient = request.form.get('email')
          message = request.form.get('message')
          job = q.enqueue(sendEmail_task, recipient, message)
          return redirect(url_for("routes.email_sent"))

      return render_template("send_email.html")
  ```
- **app/__init__.py**

  ```
  mail = Mail()

  def create_app(config_class = Config):
      app = Flask(__name__)
      from app.routes import routes
      app.register_blueprint(routes)    
      app.config.from_object(Config)

      with app.app_context():
          mail.init_app(app)

      return app
  ```
- **run.py**

> Which is outside the app folder

```
    from app import create_app

    app = create_app()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11544248/2052575)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably missing an `app.app_context().push()`. The Flask Mega Tutorial does it like [this](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/v0.22/app/tasks.py#L11), but I've done it inside the task.

Comment: so according to the folders structure above where should **app.app_context().push()** go exactly as i won't be able to import app from anywhere to call it inside the task function

Comment: guessing inside the task function. try `flask.current_app.app_context().push()`

Comment: I did this inside the task function and importing create_app function from __init__.py

`app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)`

Comment: Yup, that'll do it, too